# why such strange results for boost::timer?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, time, g++

Why boost::timer gives me such strange results?
My working solution is to use wrapper about `gettimeofday` function from `<time.h>`, but I don't understand why `boost::timer` is not working for me here. What do I do wrong?

```
class Timer {
private:

    timeval startTime;

public:

    void start(){
        gettimeofday(&startTime, NULL);
    }

    double stop(){
        timeval endTime;
        long seconds, useconds;
        double duration;

        gettimeofday(&endTime, NULL);

        seconds  = endTime.tv_sec  - startTime.tv_sec;
        useconds = endTime.tv_usec - startTime.tv_usec;

        duration = seconds + useconds/1000000.0;

        return duration;
    }

    long stop_useconds(){
        timeval endTime;
        long useconds;

        gettimeofday(&endTime, NULL);
        useconds = endTime.tv_usec - startTime.tv_usec;

        return useconds;
    }

    static void printTime(double duration){
        printf("%5.6f seconds\n", duration);
    }
};
```

test:

```
//test

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     void *vp = malloc(1024*sizeof(int));
     memset((int *)vp, 0, 1024);
    void* itab = malloc(sizeof(int)*1024*256); //1MiB table  
    if (itab) {
        memset ( (int*)itab, 0, 1024*256*sizeof (int) );
        float elapsed;

        boost::timer t;
        Timer timer = Timer();
        timer.start();

        Munge64(itab, 1024*256);

        double duration = timer.stop();
        long lt = timer.stop_useconds();
        timer.printTime(duration);
        cout << t.elapsed() << endl;
        elapsed = t.elapsed();
        cout << ios::fixed << setprecision(10) << elapsed << endl;
        cout << ios::fixed << setprecision(10) << t.elapsed() << endl;
        printf("Munge8 elapsed:%ld useconds\n", lt);

        elapsed = 0;
        free(vp);
        free(itab);
        //printf("Munge8 elapsed:%d\n", elapsed);
    }
}
```

results:

0.000100 seconds

0 << ??????????

40 << ????????????????

40 << ???????????????????????????????????

Munge8 elapsed:100 useconds

0.000100 seconds

0

40

40

Munge8 elapsed:100 useconds

0.000099 seconds

0

40

40

Munge8 elapsed:99 useconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use boost::timer - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/timer/doc/original_timer.html#Class timer

On POSIX like it measures CPU time - not wall clock time.

Consider using boost::chrono or std::chrono - you would want to look at steady_clock - as other clocks when implementing a timer if you want to isolate yourself from drift or shift in system wall clock. I expect on POSIX this will use clock_gettime on CLOCK_MONOTONIC.

Comment: thanks, I missed that this is deprecated now, because I was looking at the stale class references